# Explain why mikroC's PIC18F4550 HID example works

Tags: usb, microcontroller, pic, hid

The [mikroC compiler](http://www.mikroe.com/mikroc/pic/) has a library for HID (Human Interface Device) USB communication. In the supplied samples, they specify that the buffers below should be in USB RAMand use a PIC18F4550 as the target microcontroller.

```
unsigned char readbuff[64] absolute 0x500;   // Buffers should be in USB RAM, please consult datasheet
unsigned char writebuff[64] absolute 0x540;
```

But the PIC18F4550's datasheet says USB RAM ranges from 400h to 4FFh.

So why does their example work, when their buffers appear not to be between 400h to 4FFh?

[Link to full source](http://pastebin.com/RCNXGAdV).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf) actually says:

> Bank 4 (400h through 4FFh) is used specifically for
>   endpoint buffer control, while Banks 5 through 7 are
>   available for USB data. Depending on the type of
>   buffering being used, all but 8 bytes of Bank 4 may also
>   be available for use as USB buffer space.

So, it would appear the code you're quoting is defining buffers used for USB data, not "endpoing buffer control" since they are in bank 5 instead of bank 4.

Answer (score 0):

When USB HID mode is activated, USB RAM Memory ranges from 400h to 4FFh is assigned for buffer descriptors. Range between 500h and 7ffh is assigned for USB and user data. Important thing is all descriptor buffer and data buffer will be in ram memory range of bank 4-7.
Thank you